# Button actions not working correctly on android 9+, but works on 4-8

Tags: android, authentication, registration, android-9.0-pie

My application works from `android 4` and I assumed that by generating it this way it will work correctly on `android 9, 10` etc.

But when entering the application on devices that use `android 9` they cannot `register or log` in correctly, since the `buttons are unresponsive`. However in other versions of android they work perfectly.

```
public class LoginRequestion extends StringRequest {

    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL="http://...Login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public LoginRequestion(String usuario, String contrasena, Response.Listener<String> listener) {

        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();

        params.put("usuario", usuario);
        params.put("contrasena", contrasena);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;

        }
    }
```

Comment: by *since the buttons are unresponsive* do you mean the size of the buttons?

Comment: you are using http which is not allowed. you should use https or set networkSecurityConfig in manifest

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. Android 9 (foot) does not allow http connection ?. In any other version of android my app works very well. I don't know how to implement the change you tell me. But if I use http where is my file Login.php

Answer (score 0):

Above android 9

- Option1:

  - you create a file network_security_config, res/xml/network_security_config.

    ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
       <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
         <domain includeSubdomains="true">your_domain.com</domain>
       </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
    ```
  - In AndroidManifest:

    ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <manifest ... >
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                   ... >
           ...
         </application>
     </manifest>
    ```
- Option2; In AndroidManifest:

  ```
  <application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
  ```

  You can refer:

> https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your response again, and I am implementing what you told me in my update. a big hug

Comment: Como lo hago es la primera vez que creo una pregunta siempre lei nomas! :S

Comment: Hello, update my application with the configuration you tell me and it still does not work on android v9 (foot) in all the above works correctly.
My question is what is it that does not work on android v9

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
```

$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$contrasena = $_POST["contrasena"];

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND contrasena = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $usuario, $contrasena);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
```

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $nombre, $email, $usuario, $contrasena);

```
$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["nombre"] = $nombre;
    $response["email"] = $email;
    $response["usuario"] = $usuario;
    $response["contrasena"] = $contrasena;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```